# "Application cannot be installed in the default install location" error while updating

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, samsung-galaxy-note, application-autoupdate

I have a Galaxy note which was recently updated to ICS (about a month ago)

Today I noticed that some of the applications, that are on auto update, keeping failing to update with this message:

"Application cannot be installed in the default install location"

I have enough storage left so I am not sure what this error means or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a known problem updating apps which were moved to the SD-Card using App2SD. It does not always happen -- but if it does, a helpful work-around is:

1. move the app back to internal memory
2. run the update (should work now)
3. move the app to SD again (optional -- if you want it to be on the external SD)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think you misunderstand my question. I did not move any apps to the SD card (my phone wont let me, which is fine) but I literally can't install new apps (not updating). and sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. Is there an easy fix to this? like i said before, i have plenty of app memory.

Comment: Could it be that the apps in question have the sd card as "default install location" (the developer can declare preferences in the Manifest, and this theoretically could even include to "force" it to sd by not permitting other storage AFAIK). Does it happen with all apps, or just with some?